# npm start is not working on electron app?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, npm-install

## main.js:

```
console.warn("merhaba")
```

## package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.1.2"
  }
}
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fig3g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooi4w.png)

I just want to print to the console, but even that doesn't work.
I Deleted the node_modules folder and then run npm install. but still not working.

Comment: Hey & welcome to StackOverflow! I can't reproduce this issue - I'm getting the console output printed. One tip for questions: please include code, program output, file listings etc. as text instead of images. This makes the question more accessible & will lead to more people willing to help.